# Scrape tooltips from a graph using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, graph, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out how to scrape the tooltips values from graphs in [this url](https://coronavirus.iowa.gov/)

I can not figure out by inspecting in chrome any of the graph elements how they are rendered. Also, the html that is returned by the following statement seems to be different than what I see in chrome:

```
r = requests.get("https://coronavirus.iowa.gov")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, show your expected output, it will be helpful for figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, so parsing is little bit complicated.

You can use this example:

```
import re
import requests
import json

url = 'https://public.domo.com/embed/pages/dPRol'
url2 = 'https://public.domo.com/embed/pages/dPRol/stack?parts=metadata,datasources,drillPathURNs,domoapp'
url3 = 'https://public.domo.com/embed/pages/dPRol/cards/{urn}/render?parts=image,summary'
json_data = json.loads(json.loads(r'"{\"queryOverrides\":{\"filters\":[]},\"chartState\":{\"overrides\":{\"hide_annotation_list\":true}},\"transparent\":true,\"textColor\":\"#54585A\",\"scaleLineColor\":\"#D3D3D2\",\"imageMap\":true,\"pageLayout\":true,\"width\":793,\"height\":182,\"scale\":1,\"cardLoadContext\":{\"context\":\"page\",\"sessionId\":\"bb2fb992-d6cd-4a92-b21d-6e14a660b5e4\",\"visibilityState\":\"visible\",\"contextId\":\"dPRol\",\"trigger\":\"initial_load\"}}"'))
token = re.search(r"'x-domo-embed-token': '(.*?)'", requests.get(url).text).group(1)
data = requests.get(url2, headers={'x-domo-embed-token':token}).json()

# set search_for to one of following:
#   Individuals Tested
#   Individuals Positive
#   Total Recovered
#   Total Deaths
search_for = 'Individuals Tested'

for card in data['cards']:
    if card['title'] == search_for and \
       card['metadata']['chartType'] in ('badge_line_bar', 'badge_line_stackedbar'):
        urn = card['urn']
        break

final_data = requests.put(url3.format(urn=urn), json=json_data, headers={'X-DOMO-Embed-Token': token, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'} ).json()

for image in final_data['image']['jsonImageMap']:
    print(image['t'])
```

Prints:

```
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-24 : 52,189
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-23 : 51,765
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-22 : 48,200
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-21 : 47,410
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-20 : 45,411
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-19 : 44,929
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-18 : 44,106
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-17 : 43,951
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-16 : 43,089
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-15 : 43,708
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-14 : 42,137
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-13 : 41,523
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-12 : 38,791
Individuals Tested on 2020-05-11 : 37,522

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - works perfectly. One question: what technique did you use or where you looked to determine that url2 will provide the URNs needed by the calls in Chrome XHR section (url3 calls).

Comment: @dmornad I used Firefox developer tools - in Network tab I downloaded all requests as one big HAR archive and in text editor looked-up in that file what requests are needed to obtain the final values.